# Dataproc submit a Hadoop job via Python client

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm trying to use Dataproc API, by trying to convert a gcloud command to API, but I can't find a good example in documentation.

```
%pip install google-cloud-dataproc
```

The only good sample I found is this, which works fine:

```
from google.cloud import dataproc_v1

client = dataproc_v1.ClusterControllerClient()

project_id = 'test-project'
region = 'global'

for element in client.list_clusters(project_id, region):   
    print('Dataproc cluster name:', element.cluster_name)
```

I need to convert to Python code the following gcloud command:

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit hadoop --cluster "${CLUSTER_NAME}" \
    --class com.mycompany.product.MyClass \
    --jars "${JAR_FILE}" -- \
    --job_venv=venv.zip \
    --job_binary_path=venv/bin/python3.5 \
    --job_executes program.py \
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
project_id = 'your project'
region = 'global'

# Define Job arguments:

job_args = ['--job_venv=venv.zip',
            '--job_binary_path=venv/bin/python3.5',
            '--job_executes program.py']


job_client = dataproc_v1.JobControllerClient()

# Create Hadoop Job
hadoop_job = dataproc_v1.types.HadoopJob(jar_file_uris=[JAR_FILE], main_class='com.mycompany.product.MyClass',args=job_args)

# Define Remote cluster to send Job
job_placement = dataproc_v1.types.JobPlacement()
job_placement.cluster_name = 'your_cluster_name'

# Define Job configuration
main_job = dataproc_v1.types.Job(hadoop_job=hadoop_job, placement=job_placement)

# Send job
job_client.submit_job(project_id, region, main_job)

# Monitor in Dataproc UI or perform another API call to track status
```